# WPF styling deep nested elements

Tags: wpf

I can't override a default style attribute of a third-party component that I use in a clean way. The visual tree looks something like this:

```
A
--B
...
------------Z
--------------TextBlock
```

I try to override the style of `TextBlock` like this:

```
<Style
    TargetType="A">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style
            TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter
                Property="TextWrapping"
                Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

But this doesn't work. In live visual tree, I confirm that component `A` sees my custom style but `TextBlock` doesn't see it. However, when I try:

```
<Style
    TargetType="Z">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style
            TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter
                Property="TextWrapping"
                Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

It works though. Therefore, it seems to me that WPF forces me to add all of the child components one by one as `Style.Resources` to be able to edit the innermost child. But I don't want to define all of the resources between component `A` to `Z` just to add one simple style. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, as you've provided a working answer, and I can't see why would WPF force you to 'define all of the resources between component A to Z'.

However, here is a tip:

You can create a custom control that inherits Z and overrides OnApplyTemplate(). When OnApplyTemplate() is called you're guaranteed that the template was applied, so you can find any child control (your textbox) you want. (Just google for e.g 'wpf find child control by name' if you don't know how.) Once you have your textbox, you can change its' wrapping from code. 
I had to customize a Ribbon control once, and that approach greatly simplified the task.